# How to end a while loop containing a time.sleep?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I got a code like this:

```
import time
try:
    while True:
        print("Hello World")
        time.sleep(10)
except:
    print("Ctrl+z was pressed")  #Doesn't get executed
```

When I try to execute this code in python 3, the stuff in my except block does not execute. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will always be stuck in the while loop, as the condition is always True. you will never exit the try condition and so never execute the except block.

If I am correct, crtl+z does only make the program sleep, so is no termination signal like crtl+c, which would break the loop and get the except block to execute.

Comment: Ah thank you, I should press ctrl+c instead of ctrl+z to raise the keyboardinterrupt. My bad!